# How to add view from container view that occupies all view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicontainerview

I have a UIContainerVIew. From this, I want load a UIView with opacity in all viewController.

```
float width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
float height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

self.myView = [[ITSMyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, width, height)];
[self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.superview.superview.frame.origin.x, self.view.superview.superview.frame.origin.y, width, height)];

[self.view addSubview:self.myView];
```

How can I add this correctly and show in all view from UIContainerView? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`for (UIViewController * vc in self.parent.childViewControllers) {
 vc.view.addSubView(viewtoAdd)
}`